# Is that possible to replace screenshots in released iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios

i got approved & my app released 2 days ago & now my client needs to update screenshots to high quality.

Is that possible to delete all & replace with new ones or i should upload a new binary?

Even if i update Binary once gain , i should update my version also in such a case did apple approve my app with update version?

Thanks

Comment: No need to update again, Bcoz you should change the screen shot,description name, Email Address and Supporting URL's etc., The only thing shouldn't changed ie) seller name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to update a new binary only when you need to change the app icon. You can manage your screenshots whenever you like.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply replace the screenshot asset, you would not have to upload a new binary.